# transform string scala in an elegant way

Tags: regex, string, scala, split

I have the following input string: `val s = 19860803 000000`

I want to convert it to  1986/08/03
I tried this `s.split(" ").head`, but this is not complete

is there any elegant scala coding way with regex to get the expected result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a date like pattern using 3 capture groups, and match the following space and the 6 digits.

In the replacement use the 3 groups in the replacement with the forward slashes.

```
val s = "19860803 000000"
val result = s.replaceAll("^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})\\h\\d{6}$", "$1/$2/$3")
```

Output

```
result: String = 1986/08/03
```

Answer (score 1):

i haven't tested this, but i think the following will work

```
val expr = raw"(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}) (.*)".r

val formatted = "19860803 000000" match {
  case expr(year,month,day,_) =>. s"$year/$month/$day"
}
```

scala docs have a lot of good info
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/util/matching/Regex.html

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, without a regular expression, by using `slice` and `take`.

```
val s = "19860803 000000"
val year = s.take(4)
val month = s.slice(4,6)
val day = s.slice(6,8)
val result = s"$year/$month/$day"
```

Or as a one liner

```
val result = Seq(s.take(4), s.slice(4,6), s.slice(6,8)).mkString("/")
```